# error :too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am currently building a model that has been followed by steps used in many projects but I had a problem of too many values to unpack and this is the code below

```py
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(20,))
en_x=  Embedding(self.sequence_length, self.embedding_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(200, return_state=True))
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(en_x)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dex=  Embedding(self.sequence_length, self.embedding_dim)
final_dex= dex(decoder_inputs)
```

this is the model fit function

```py
    model.fit(self.train_x, self.train_y,
                        epochs=self.epochs,
                        batch_size=self.batch_size,
                        sample_weight=self.train_mask,
                        shuffle=True, 
                        callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpoint],
                        validation_data=(self.val_x, self.val_y, self.val_mask))
```

and i getting this error

```py
  177                         en_x=  Embedding(self.sequence_length, self.embedding_dim)(encoder_inputs)
    178                         encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(200, return_state=True))
--> 179                         encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(en_x)
    180                         encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    181 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `encoder_outputs, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)`

Answer (score 0):

```
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(en_x)
```

This code expects `encoder(en_x)` to return a sequence of three values.  But it returned more than that, which caused the error.

You haven't shown the code for that function, so I can't provide any further explanation.